# Double rows in recursive CTE hierarchy

Tags: sql-server

I don't get it why I get double rows as a result

```
                ;with cteP as (
                      Select GROUNDID
                                   ,OBJECTID
                            ,MAINGROUNDID 
                            ,PathID = cast(GROUNDID as varchar(max))
                      From   PMEGROUND
                      Where  REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(MAINGROUNDID)),' ',NULL)  is Null
                                   --AND DATAAREAID = 'sgv'
                      Union  All
                      Select GROUNDID      = r.GROUNDID
                                   ,OBJECTID       = r.OBJECTID
                            ,MAINGROUNDID  = r.MAINGROUNDID 
                            ,PathID = p.PathID+concat(',',cast(r.GROUNDID as varchar(max)))
                      From   PMEGROUND r
                      Join   cteP p on r.MAINGROUNDID  = p.GROUNDID)
                Select 
                      PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID,
                      --PMEOBJECT.GROUNDID,
                      --cteP.GROUNDID,
                      B.Lvl1
                      ,B.Lvl2
                      ,B.Lvl3
                      ,B.Lvl4
                FROM PMEOBJECT
                Left Join cteP
                      ON cteP.GROUNDID = PMEOBJECT.GROUNDID
                Cross Apply (
                                Select Lvl1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                                      ,Lvl2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                                      ,Lvl3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                                      ,Lvl4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) B(xDim)
                             ) B
                Where cteP.GROUNDID IS NOT NULL
                Order By OBJECTID
```

EDIT: This is my current data set:

```
                CREATE TABLE PMEGROUND (
                    OBJECTID nvarchar(20),
                    GROUNDID nvarchar(20),
                    MAINGROUNDID nvarchar(20)
                );

                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('2','6','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('3','7','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('4','8','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('5','9','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('6','10','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('7','11','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('8','14','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('9','15','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('10','16','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('11','17','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12','18','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('13','19','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('14','20','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('15','21','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('16','22','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('17','23','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('18','24','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('19','25','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('20','26','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12669','2610','26')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12670','2620','26')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12671','2630','26')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12672','2640','26')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12673','2650','26')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('21','27','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('22','28','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('23','29','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('24','30','')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12674','3010','30')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12675','3020','30')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12676','3030','30')
                insert into PMEGROUND Values ('12677','3040','30')


                CREATE TABLE PMEOBJECT (
                    OBJECTID nvarchar(20),
                    GROUNDID nvarchar(20)
                );

                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('1','')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('2','6')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('3','7')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('4','8')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('5','9')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('6','10')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('7','11')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('8','14')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('9','15')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('10','16')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('11','17')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('13','19')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('14','20')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('15','21')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('16','22')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('17','23')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('18','24')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('19','25')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('20','26')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12669','2610')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12670','2620')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12671','2630')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12672','2640')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12673','2650')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('21','27')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('22','28')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('23','29')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('24','30')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12674','3010')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12675','3020')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12676','3030')
                insert into PMEOBJECT Values ('12677','3040')
```

EDIT: How the result data set looks like:

```
                OBJECTID,GROUNDID,Lvl1,Lvl2,Lvl3,Lvl4
                1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
                10      016     016     NULL    NULL    NULL
                11      017     017     NULL    NULL    NULL
                12669   02610   02610   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12669   02610   026     02610   NULL    NULL
                12670   02620   026     02620   NULL    NULL
                12670   02620   02620   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12671   02630   02630   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12671   02630   026     02630   NULL    NULL
                12672   02640   026     02640   NULL    NULL
                12672   02640   02640   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12673   02650   02650   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12673   02650   026     02650   NULL    NULL
                12674   03010   030     03010   NULL    NULL
                12674   03010   03010   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12675   03020   03020   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12675   03020   030     03020   NULL    NULL
                12676   03030   030     03030   NULL    NULL
                12676   03030   03030   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12677   03040   03040   NULL    NULL    NULL
                12677   03040   030     03040   NULL    NULL
                13      019     019     NULL    NULL    NULL
                14      020     020     NULL    NULL    NULL
                15      021     021     NULL    NULL    NULL
                16      022     022     NULL    NULL    NULL
                17      023     023     NULL    NULL    NULL
                18      024     024     NULL    NULL    NULL
                19      025     025     NULL    NULL    NULL
                2       006     006     NULL    NULL    NULL
                20      026     026     NULL    NULL    NULL
                21      027     027     NULL    NULL    NULL
                22      028     028     NULL    NULL    NULL
                23      029     029     NULL    NULL    NULL
                24      030     030     NULL    NULL    NULL
                3       007     007     NULL    NULL    NULL
                4       008     008     NULL    NULL    NULL
                5       009     009     NULL    NULL    NULL
                6       010     010     NULL    NULL    NULL
                7       011     011     NULL    NULL    NULL
                8       014     014     NULL    NULL    NULL
                9       015     015     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And the original tables PMEGround and PMEObject work the following way:

- PMEOBJECT has a unique OBJECTID, but multiple objects can have the
  same GROUNDID. Some objects don't have a GROUNDID at all, simply a
  blank field (converted to NULL).

  - The PMEGROUND table contains all the
    GROUNDID's, and in that table also GROUNDID's refer to each others'
    GROUNDID, since there is also a hierarchy within the PMEGROUND. This means that one 10 different GROUNDID's can have all the same MAINGROUNDID, and this MAINGROUNDID is also stored as a GROUNDID, which in turn also can point to another MAINGROUNDID. In total this will have maximum of 4 levels.

Any ideas on why I have double rows in the query? The OBJECTID should stay unique.

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: You've posted your attempt, which is great, however, we can't run your query as we don't have access to your data. Could you post what your data looks like as **formatted** `text` please (or even better as DDL and DML statements). Also, what do you want your final result set to look like? Thanks.

Comment: Try to change `UNION ALL` with simply `UNION` in your CTE, that MIGHT remove the duplicates. If that doesn't work, we would need to see your data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I added the dataset of both tables I use in my query, since I tried Union without success. I also changed the result to look exactly like what I get and what needs to be changed.

Comment: Is there anyone out there who is able to reenact the same issue with the dataset I provided?